# If statement always returning true when comparing ints - Lehmann Algorithm/test

Tags: java

I'm implementing a method that generates a number and checks if its prime using Lehmanns method. I got it all working apart from my checking if it's prime. So n is the randomly generated number and prime is the result after running Lehmanns algorithm. Essentially if the result of it is `1` or `-1` `mod n` then it might be prime. Java doesn't like negative module and `-1` `mod n` will always be `n -1` so I did the check like so:

```
       int n = 7;
       int prime = 6;
    if(prime != 1 || prime != n - 1)
    {
        System.out.println("here");
    }
```

Now the issue is this is still printing "here" when it shouldn't even if I set `prime` to `1`. I might just be tired because it's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: When prime is 1, then the second condition `prime != n-1` is true (because 1 != 0), thus, the entire or condition is true.

Comment: This if statement will only be false if `prime` is 1 and `n` happens to be 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are checking OR `||` condition... Use AND `&&`

```
if(prime != 1 && prime != n - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`prime != 1 || prime != n-1` will evaluate true when prime is not 1 OR when prime is not n-1. So even if prime is 1, it will be true since prime is not n-1.

You may instead want an AND condition.

```
if (prime != 1 && prime != n-1)
```